# changing the background color of a v-list header

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am tying to change the color of a v-list header item. I seem to only be able to change the colour of the title but not the whole tile. Note that I need this to be reactive since the background color I am trying to change will not remain the same over time.

I have tried using the color property on the v-list-tile-content but it does not do anything. Then I tried the same on the v-list-tile-title but this only changes the title part not the action/avatar part

In other words it's like changing the colour of the Dining title in the following codepen https://codepen.io/patrick2009/pen/pmdgNz

```
 <v-list-tile-content color="red">
     <v-list-tile-title>{{ subItem.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
 </v-list-tile-content>
```

Something like that would be nice!

Thanks guys,

Pat

Comment: As per API, `color` prop should be on `v-list-tile` component. But it seems to be bugged, or changed recently? Maybe use `class="red"` as a workaround? (Or maybe `color` prop should just change text color, not background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** I have updated my answer to show how you can add `css` dynamically, using `props`.

Example:

```js
const myList = {
  template: "#my-list",
  props: ["color", "hover"],
  mounted() {
    var css = `
    .v-list__group__header { 
      background-color: ${this.color};
    }
    .v-list__group__header:hover {
      background-color: ${this.hover} !important;
    }
    `;
    var style = document.createElement("style");
    if (style.styleSheet) {
      style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
      style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(style);
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          action: "local_activity",
          title: "Attractions",
          items: [{
            title: "List Item"
          }]
        },
        {
          action: "restaurant",
          title: "Dining",
          active: true,
          items: [{
              title: "Breakfast & brunch"
            },
            {
              title: "New American"
            },
            {
              title: "Sushi"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          action: "school",
          title: "Education",
          items: [{
            title: "List Item"
          }]
        },
        {
          action: "directions_run",
          title: "Family",
          items: [{
            title: "List Item"
          }]
        },
        {
          action: "healing",
          title: "Health",
          items: [{
            title: "List Item"
          }]
        },
        {
          action: "content_cut",
          title: "Office",
          items: [{
            title: "List Item"
          }]
        },
        {
          action: "local_offer",
          title: "Promotions",
          items: [{
            title: "List Item"
          }]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    myList
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.5.14/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
        <my-list color="red" hover="blue"></my-list>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="my-list">
  <v-card>
    <v-toolbar color="teal" dark>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Topics</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>more_vert</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar>
    <v-list>
      <v-list-group v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" v-model="item.active" :prepend-icon="item.action" no-action>
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>
           </v-list-tile>
         </template>
        <v-list-tile v-for="subItem in item.items" :key="subItem.title" @click="">
          <v-list-tile-content color="red">
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ subItem.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>{{ subItem.action }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-card>
</script>
```

---

[[CodePen Mirror]](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/VOrjme)

---

Old Answer:

Looks like you have to set this via `css` for that class.. The class you'll have to target is `v-list__group__header`.

***EDIT:*** You can also use a `:hover` "event" to change the `background-color` on hover - unfortunately, this requires you to use the `!important` modifier, which is typically frowned upon. Figured I would mention it regardless.

```
.v-list__group__header:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I did test that solution but it does not allow me to use a property as background color (reactive). The color needs to be a props I can send to the component.

Comment: @user2097439 - I have updated my answer to show how you can achieve this by dynamically adding `css` via `props`.